Will python multiprocessing deep copy parameters using spawn method?
Assume I am using multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn'). When creating a process using multiprocessing.Process(target=fun, args=(a,)), I am wondering whether a will be deep copied. From previous questions python multiprocessing arguments: deep copy? , it seems that using fork start method will not copy parameters. But does it hold for other start methods such as spawn or forkserver?
My second question is, if deep copy is performed, is there any approach to avoid such a copy without using fork start method (since fork can only be used on Linux and is not thread safe)? This is particularly useful when the memory does not support copy large classes such as high-dimensional tensors.
I have Googled extensively but could not find an answer yet.

Parameters are passed by serializing them with pickle and then de-serializing the pickled data in the child process. This results in the equivalent of doing a deep copy. When you use the fork method, the child process inherits the main process's memory but "copy on write" is used so that when a change is made to the object in the child process, a copy is made of at least some portion of the memory used by the object (and that "change" might just be due to updating reference counts).

you can avoid the copy by using shared memory. obviously python objects cannot be shared, you can only share things like arrays of numbers.

without fork a copy must be made because python objects are made up of pointers, and all those pointers won't correspond to anything in the second process, a pointer in one process means nothing in another process.

@AhmedAEK As you probably know, you can share objects if you make them managed objects. But then when you make a method call on the object, you are actually invoking a method on a proxy object which then must marshal the call to the actual process in which the "actual" object resides. So method calls have additional overhead. An example would be a multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict instance. But you can create your own custom managed objects.
